# Uploading Image to Google Drive with Proper Error Handling in Android

Tags: android, image, performance, file-upload, google-drive-api

I have developed a Swift code to upload a PDF file to Google Drive using the Drive API. The PDF file uploads successfully, but sometimes I get a timeout message in the log, which may be due to my poor connection. I need guidance on:

How to handle timeout or connection issues in the code to prevent upload failures.
How to modify the code to upload an image file instead of a PDF.
Here is my current implementation for uploading a PDF file:

```
import android.util.Log;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Tasks;
import com.google.api.client.http.FileContent;
import com.google.api.services.drive.Drive;
import com.google.api.services.drive.model.File;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.concurrent.Executor;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;

public class DriveServiceHelper {

    private final Executor mExecutor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
    private Drive mDriveService;

    public DriveServiceHelper(Drive mDriveService){

        this.mDriveService = mDriveService;
    }

    public Task<String> createFilePdf(String filePath){
        return Tasks.call(mExecutor, () -> {
            File fileMetaData = new File();
            fileMetaData.setName("MyPDFFile");

            java.io.File file = new java.io.File(filePath);

            FileContent mediaContent = new FileContent("application/pdf",file);

            File myFile = null;
            try {
                myFile = mDriveService.files().create(fileMetaData,mediaContent).execute();
            }catch (Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
                Log.i("myissue", e.getMessage());
            }

            if (myFile == null){
                throw new IOException("Null result when requesting file creation");
            }
            return myFile.getId();


        });
    }
}
```

```
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignIn;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInAccount;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInClient;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInOptions;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.Scope;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnFailureListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnSuccessListener;
import com.google.api.client.extensions.android.http.AndroidHttp;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.extensions.android.gms.auth.GoogleAccountCredential;
import com.google.api.client.json.gson.GsonFactory;
import com.google.api.services.drive.Drive;
import com.google.api.services.drive.DriveScopes;

import java.util.Collections;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    DriveServiceHelper driveServiceHelper;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        
        requestSignIn();
    }

    private void requestSignIn() {
        GoogleSignInOptions signInOptions = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
                .requestEmail()
                .requestScopes(new Scope(DriveScopes.DRIVE_FILE))
                .build();

        GoogleSignInClient client = GoogleSignIn.getClient(this,signInOptions);

        startActivityForResult(client.getSignInIntent(),400);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        switch (requestCode){
            case 400:
                if (resultCode == RESULT_OK){
                    handleSignInIntent(data);
                    break;
                }
        }
    }

    private void handleSignInIntent(Intent data) {
        GoogleSignIn.getSignedInAccountFromIntent(data)
                .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<GoogleSignInAccount>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(GoogleSignInAccount googleSignInAccount) {
                        GoogleAccountCredential credential = GoogleAccountCredential
                                .usingOAuth2(MainActivity.this, Collections.singleton(DriveScopes.DRIVE_FILE));

                        credential.setSelectedAccount(googleSignInAccount.getAccount());

                        Drive googleDriveServices = new Drive.Builder(
                                AndroidHttp.newCompatibleTransport(),
                                new GsonFactory(),
                                credential)
                                .setApplicationName("uploadtodrive")
                                .build();

                        driveServiceHelper = new DriveServiceHelper(googleDriveServices);

                    }
                })
                .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {

                    }
                });
    }

    public void uploadPdfFile(View v){

        ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
        progressDialog.setTitle("Uploading to google Drive");
        progressDialog.setMessage("Please wait........");
        progressDialog.show();

        String filePath = "/storage/emulated/0/mypdf.pdf";

        driveServiceHelper.createFilePdf(filePath).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(String s) {
                progressDialog.dismiss();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Uploaded Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        })
                .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                        progressDialog.dismiss();
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Check your google Drive api key",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });



    }
}
```

**Please Help for this part. I am stuck here for two days**. thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Set appropriate MIME type:

In order to upload a specific file type to Drive, you have to specify its MIME type on the media content. In your case, this is handled by [FileContent](https://googleapis.dev/java/google-http-client/latest/com/google/api/client/http/FileContent.html):

```
FileContent mediaContent = new FileContent("application/pdf",file);
```

So you would have to replace `application/pdf` with the appropriate MIME type (see for example the [supported MIME types in G Suite documents](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/ref-export-formats)). Possible MIME types for images include `image/jpeg` and `image/png`. For example, you could do this:

```
FileContent mediaContent = new FileContent("image/jpeg",file);
```

#### Note:

- I'm assuming that you do have an image on the provided `filePath`.

#### Reference:

- [MIME types (IANA media types)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/MIME_types)

Comment: Please note, Tasks.call (call(java.util.concurrent.Executor, java.util.concurrent.Callable<TResult>) is deprecated and consider a replacement